# Submit automatically an RSS feed to RSS Feeds directory

Tags: php, rss, submit

How can I submit an RSS Feed automatically to a list of RSS Feeds directory?

Comment: It would depend on what interface the directory provided for accepting submissions.

Comment: You'd probably be better off by using an existing service, such as Ping-o-matic: http://pingomatic.com/

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use other services. Any other opinion?

Comment: @fiskfisk, your proposal was the only solution. Can you post an answer, so I can mark your answer as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably be better off by using an existing service, such as [Ping-o-matic](http://pingomatic.com/). Wordpress also lists several [other XML-RPC ping services](http://codex.wordpress.org/Update_Services#XML-RPC_Ping_Services) in their Codex.